# How to make the "Save as" Dialog like Notepad do?

Tags: notepad

[image]

if i set the OFN_ENABLEHOOK in OPENFILENAME, it turn to old style.

[image]

if i set the OFN_EXPLORER in OPENFILENAME, then it turn to Explorer style.

[image]

Both is not i want.

Comment: You need to use the new `IFileSaveDialog` interface instead of the old `GetSaveFileName`. Add the combo box with `IFileDialogCustomize::AddComoboBox`.

Comment: Great! This wroks!